# Why won't Visual Studios show me my Unity script?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mono

I need help with Visual Studios.  I am new to Unity and Visual Studios, and for some reason, Visual Studios won't show me my script.  I created a script, which I just made, so Visual Studios should have showed me a default Unity script, but it shows nothing.  I think it has something to do with Mono because that was the issue in the beginning, but I downloaded twice and the install was successful.

Comment: well did you try to double click the script in order to open it? A bit unclear what you are asking without more information ...

Answer (score 0):

You can always look for another text editor:
Atom
Sublime
Notepad++
Then, in Unity, go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools and find External Script Editor (or a similar setting), then change that to your new editor.